# Notification not sent to android wear device

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working through the [Creating notification tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html)  and I wanted to know if the below code should live in the `mobile` package or the `wear` package?

```
int notificationId = 001;
// Build intent for notification content
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ViewEventActivity.class);
viewIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_ID, eventId);
PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
    .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
    .setContentText(eventLocation)
    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I also am debugging this locally with an actual android device and a wear emulator. Should I be expecting the notification to be propagated from the phone to the wear device in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your phone to send the notification to the "wear" device, then it as to live in your "mobile" package.

This is the "normal" way.

Sometimes you want to create in context notification and in this case you need to write a "wear" activity or service to generate them.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a duplicate of [Android wear not show notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641967/android-wear-not-show-notification)

---

Make sure that you have given the Android Wear app on your device access to notifications.

In 4.4: **Settings > Security > Notification Access** 

In L Preview: **Settings > Sound & Notifications > Notification Access**

Within the Notification access screen, make sure that **Android Wear** is checked.