# Android wear not show notification

Tags: android, wear-os

I've probblem. My android wear emulator not show notification.
Here is my code for mobile:

```
private void notifyToWear() {
        NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                .setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Request text")
                .setContentText("Speak something then your phone will search it.")
                .extend(wearableExtender);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

I call it when button in MainActivity click. In my phone it show notification but in android wear emulator not show.
Notes: 
+ I've connected between android phone & android wear emualtor. I tested with Card Example in Android Wear App. It's working.

Thanks.

-- Update --
Code perform click button:

```
(findViewById(R.id.btn_request_text)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Call request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyToWear();
            }
        });
```

When I click to button Toast is show.

--- Update ---
I also run ElizaChat & RecipeAssistant in Wear Sample.
But it not working too.

Comment: can you post the code of the button? to see how you call this code?

Comment: I've update problem. Can u help me ?

Comment: Any luck solving this?

Comment: Here is my prob: I'm not enable notification access for my app so I can't share any notification from my phone to wear. see answer from @VarPete

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure that you have given the Android Wear app on your device access to notifications.

In 4.4:  **Settings > Security > Notification Access** 

In L Preview: **Settings > Sound & Notifications > Notification Access**

Within the Notification access screen, make sure that **Android Wear** is checked.

Comment: Thanks so so so much !
I have question why android developer page not notice about it. :(

Comment: WOW :) is it really the solution? Why Android didn't mention this?!

Comment: I enabled the notification for Android Wear in Notification Access. I am trying ElizaChat Android sample, phone gets notification but not the emulator. I do have google's Android wear app.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 7, go to: Settings > Apps > click cogwheel > Special Access > Notification access > Android Wear > click switch for Tasker. See screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NotificationCompact.Builder notBuilder = 
                                   new NotificationCompact.Builder(this);
notBuilder.setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Text");
WearableNotifications.Builder wearBuilder = 
                                 new WearableNotifications.Builder(notBuilder);
Notification not = wearBuilder.build();

NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
manager.notify(0,not);
```

I hope this will help you..