# Android Wear Emulator not getting notification

Tags: android, wear-os

I downloaded Android wear app from play store and enabled notification access in Handheld Device by going to settings -> security -> other -> Notification Access (enabled). When I tested after pairing wear emulator with handheld device (Samsung s6), I could change the watch face as per my changes in handheld but when I tested notifications,  its not popping up in wear emulator.

What could be the reason﻿?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645080/android-wear-notification-not-showing), maybe you have your app muted on Android Wear. The "mute app" button appears in every ongoing notification displayed on Wear and maybe you have clicked it accidentally. When app was muted on Android Wear device, this was preventing any notifications from appearing on watch.

> While posting any ongoing notification from watch, there will be extra action added automatically. It is called "Mute app" and probably it was pressed in some point in time during development by accident.
>
> Muted apps can be managed in the Android Wear companion app on Settings screen. This can be fairly hard to debug because any code is invoked without any error and there is also no logs in the LogCat about the fact that app is muted.

From this [thread](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056843?hl=en), swipe all the way down from the top of your watch’s screen, and touch Mute to turn mute on or off. When your watch is muted, you’ll see a Mute icon on your watch's screen.

[image: sample emulator screen]

Check also this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641967/android-wear-not-show-notification).